# Как отправить position item recycleView на виджет?

Tags: android, виджет, recycleview

Есть recycleView, для которого установлен longClick:

как мне передать позицию item в AppWidgetProvider?

```
@Override
public void onLongClick(View view, int position) {
    MainActivity.this.openContextMenu(view);
}

@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
                                ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
    if (v.getId() == R.id.recycle_view){
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_recycle, menu);
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    AdapterContextMenuInfo menuInfo = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
    switch (item.getItemId()){
        case R.id.move:
            /*
            ?????
             */
            break;
    }
    return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
}
```

Comment: Посмотрите тут https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26466877/how-to-create-context-menu-for-recyclerview

Comment: Возникает ошибка, String resource ID #0x1, сделал все как описали, но после установки onContextItemSelected в самом activity, и после попытки вывести position получаю такую ошибку, не встречали? Возможно adapter неправильно передаю

Comment: Оказывается в Toast передавал int переменную, которую не воспринимает, из-за этого получал такую ошибку.

Comment: Проблема решена с помощью [How to create context menu for RecyclerView](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27886458/9386125)